# Lower quality printing on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, printing

I have a computer with two partitions, a Windows 7 partition, and a Windows 8 partition.

I have a printer (a Star TSP700II) connected to the computer, and am using the same drivers for both (Star doesn't provide Windows 8 drivers, so I am using the Windows 7 drivers).

Both are 64-bit Windows. The computer itself is a Dell, Windows 7 is the OEM install, Windows 8 I have installed myself, but have been on Dell's website and downloaded the computers Windows 8 drivers using the service tag. The printer works on both, but on Windows 8 the text is slightly fuzzy/blurry compared to Windows 7, and it is causing us issues.

Is there any obvious reason this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the most obvious reason would be that the quality is set differently on the two machines. Comb through all the print settings and make sure. Otherwise, ensure that you're using the same driver on both machines.

Comment: I spent an obscene amount of time going through the settings on both, identical in every way! I was [trying to print a WPF form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936408/printdialog-printvisual-prints-wpf-form-at-lower-quality-on-windows-8), and on Windows 8 the quality is lower than on 7, I think it's to do with the way the form itself is rendered in Windows 8, I've never been as frustrated with such a seemingly simple problem in my life!